# C# AES Encryption Byte Array

Tags: c#, encryption, cryptography, aes

I want to encrypt byte array. So first I try it in [this site](http://extranet.cryptomathic.com/aescalc/index?key=00000000000000000000000000000000&iv=00000000000000000000000000000000&input=1EA0353A7D2947D8BBC6AD6FB52FCA84&mode=cbc&action=Encrypt&output=1EA0353A7D2947D8BBC6AD6FB52FCA84).

- **key** = 00000000000000000000000000000000
- **IV**  = 00000000000000000000000000000000
- **Input Data** = 1EA0353A7D2947D8BBC6AD6FB52FCA84
- **Type** = CBC

It calculated this

- **Encrypted Output** = C5537C8EFFFCC7E152C27831AFD383BA

Then I use **System.Security.Cryptography**  library and calculate it. But it gives me different result. Could you help me for that situation?

**Code**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

using System.IO;
using System.Security.Cryptography;

namespace DesfireCalculation
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        byte key_no = 0x00;
        byte[] key = new byte[16] { 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00};
        byte[] IV = new byte[16] { 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00 };
        byte[] rndB = new byte[16] { 0x1E,0xA0,0x35,0x3A,0x7D,0x29,0x47,0xD8,0xBB,0xC6,0xAD,0x6F,0xB5,0x2F,0xCA,0x84 };

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                byte[] res=EncryptStringToBytes_Aes(BitConverter.ToString(rndB), key, IV);
                string res_txt = BitConverter.ToString(res);
                Console.WriteLine(res_txt);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error: {0}", ex.Message);
            }
        }

        static byte[] EncryptStringToBytes_Aes(byte[] Data, byte[] Key, byte[] IV)
        {
            // Check arguments.
            if (Key == null || Key.Length <= 0)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("Key");
            if (IV == null || IV.Length <= 0)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("IV");
            byte[] encrypted;

            // Create an Aes object
            // with the specified key and IV.
            using (Aes aesAlg = Aes.Create())
            {
                aesAlg.Key = Key;
                aesAlg.IV = IV;
                aesAlg.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
                aesAlg.BlockSize = 128;
                aesAlg.FeedbackSize = 128;
                aesAlg.KeySize = 128;

                // Create an encryptor to perform the stream transform.
                ICryptoTransform encryptor = aesAlg.CreateEncryptor(aesAlg.Key, aesAlg.IV);

                // Create the streams used for encryption.
                using (MemoryStream msEncrypt = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    using (CryptoStream csEncrypt = new CryptoStream(msEncrypt, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                    {
                        using (StreamWriter swEncrypt = new StreamWriter(csEncrypt))
                        {
                            //Write all data to the stream.
                             swEncrypt.Write(Data);
                        }
                        encrypted = msEncrypt.ToArray();
                    }
                }
            }

            // Return the encrypted bytes from the memory stream.
            return encrypted;    
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why convert the input byte array to a string?

Comment: @Magnus I found example here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.aes?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: For me it gives A2E4E50D343BEA0A222B643A48E37644

Comment: @Magnus I changed to function for byte array. This solved return length data's length problem. But it still different answer from the example.

Comment: @eocron Thank you for interest. Do you have a different result every time?

Comment: No, just this one.

Comment: @eocron I changed the code and data. Could you try encryption for this version and tell me the result?

Comment: Beware that a lot of these "online" calculators are utter shit. The zero padding (a default for the now deprecated PHP mcrypt function) is just an initial warning. Try and find official test vectors instead (e.g. those from NIST).

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The site is stating:

```
Input Data (It will be padded with zeroes if necessary.)
```

The padding is really important in cryptography.

**So make sure you're using:
`aes.Padding = PaddingMode.Zeros;`**

Without it you will get longer results with padding bytes for this case.

EDIT: For real case scenarios you should probably stay with the default: PKCS #7. @WimCoenen has good point why. Check the comments.

The another issue with your code is: **You're setting Key and IV before setting their sizes.**

This is **wrong**:

```
        aesAlg.Key = Key;
        aesAlg.IV = IV;
        aesAlg.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
        aesAlg.BlockSize = 128;
        aesAlg.FeedbackSize = 128;
        aesAlg.KeySize = 128;
```

This is **correct** order:

```
        aesAlg.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
        aesAlg.KeySize = 128;
        aesAlg.BlockSize = 128;
        aesAlg.FeedbackSize = 128;
        aesAlg.Padding = PaddingMode.Zeros;
        aesAlg.Key = key;
        aesAlg.IV = iv;
```

Yet another issue with your code is you're using **StreamWriter** to write to the crypto stream:

```
using (StreamWriter swEncrypt = new StreamWriter(csEncrypt))
{
    //Write all data to the stream.
    swEncrypt.Write(Data);
}
```

**StreamWriter** probably messes up everything. It was designed for writing text in particular encoding.

Check this code below for my implementation that is working for your case.

```
public class AesCryptographyService 
{
    public byte[] Encrypt(byte[] data, byte[] key, byte[] iv)
    {
        using (var aes = Aes.Create())
        {
            aes.KeySize = 128;
            aes.BlockSize = 128;
            aes.Padding = PaddingMode.Zeros;

            aes.Key = key;
            aes.IV = iv;

            using (var encryptor = aes.CreateEncryptor(aes.Key, aes.IV))
            {
                return PerformCryptography(data, encryptor);
            }
        }
    }

    public byte[] Decrypt(byte[] data, byte[] key, byte[] iv)
    {
        using (var aes = Aes.Create())
        {
            aes.KeySize = 128;
            aes.BlockSize = 128;
            aes.Padding = PaddingMode.Zeros;

            aes.Key = key;
            aes.IV = iv;

            using (var decryptor = aes.CreateDecryptor(aes.Key, aes.IV))
            {
                return PerformCryptography(data, decryptor);
            }
        }
    }

    private byte[] PerformCryptography(byte[] data, ICryptoTransform cryptoTransform)
    {
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        using (var cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(ms, cryptoTransform, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
        {
            cryptoStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
            cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock();

            return ms.ToArray();
        }
    }
}

var key = new byte[16] { 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00};
var iv = new byte[16] { 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00 };
var input = new byte[16] { 0x1E,0xA0,0x35,0x3A,0x7D,0x29,0x47,0xD8,0xBB,0xC6,0xAD,0x6F,0xB5,0x2F,0xCA,0x84 };

var crypto = new AesCryptographyService();

var encrypted = crypto.Encrypt(input, key, iv);
var str = BitConverter.ToString(encrypted).Replace("-", "");
Console.WriteLine(str);
```

It will output the result:

```
C5537C8EFFFCC7E152C27831AFD383BA
```

Which is the same as the one on the site you're referencing:

[image]

EDIT:

I've changed your function, so it will output correct result:

```
static byte[] EncryptStringToBytes_Aes(byte[] data, byte[] key, byte[] iv)
{
    // Check arguments.
    if (key == null || key.Length <= 0)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("key");
    if (iv == null || iv.Length <= 0)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("iv");
    byte[] encrypted;

    // Create an Aes object
    // with the specified key and IV.
    using (Aes aesAlg = Aes.Create())
    {
        aesAlg.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
        aesAlg.KeySize = 128;
        aesAlg.BlockSize = 128;
        aesAlg.FeedbackSize = 128;
        aesAlg.Padding = PaddingMode.Zeros;
        aesAlg.Key = key;
        aesAlg.IV = iv;

        // Create an encryptor to perform the stream transform.
        ICryptoTransform encryptor = aesAlg.CreateEncryptor(aesAlg.Key, aesAlg.IV);

        // Create the streams used for encryption.
        using (MemoryStream msEncrypt = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (CryptoStream csEncrypt = new CryptoStream(msEncrypt, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
            {
                csEncrypt.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
                csEncrypt.FlushFinalBlock();

                encrypted = msEncrypt.ToArray();
            }
        }
    }

    // Return the encrypted bytes from the memory stream.
    return encrypted;    
}
```

Comment: +1 Good catch. But note that the default padding is PKCS #7 for a good reason: with zero padding, you'll get the extra zeroes back when decrypting because there's no way to distinguish between zero bytes at the end of the plaintext or the ones added by the padding, unless you add your own packaging structure to the plaintext before encrypting.

Comment: @WimCoenen That's right. Added your suggestion to the answer.

Comment: @BART I implemented the code but I receive padded zeroes in the decrypted byte[](my data is 11 bytes and the blocksize is 128): Original:   0A0963657274206E616D65
Round Trip: 0A0963657274206E616D650000000000  
how can i avoid it

Comment: Why are you calling FlushFinalBlock() explicitly, when this is also done by the implicit Dispose() that is called when using "using"?

Answer (score 1):

The input data is different hence the result is different as well.
On the site your plaintext is '`C5537C8EFFFCC7E152C27831AFD383BA`' and in the code is 
'`B969FDFE56FD91FC9DE6F6F213B8FD1E`'

Comment: thanks for interest and attention. I edited the code and example. But there is still different result for example and my code.